# How to use move_uploaded_file() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload an image in a folder named upload which i created in my plugin. I m using

```
<input type="file" name="upload_captcha_background" id="upload_captcha_background" />
```

plz suggest how can i upload image in uplaod folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are uploading from plugin, then you need to look at 
[wp_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) if you want to change the directory of upload folder then you should check out this tutorial: [Smarter handling of WordPress plugin uploads](http://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins/) basically wp_handle_upload uses the path returned from [wp upload dir](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) you can override that path by following the tutorial i linked. Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

Ok here is some sample code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['upload_captcha_background'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

function my_upload_dir($upload) {

  $upload['subdir'] = '/sub-dir-to-use' . $upload['subdir'];

  $upload['path']   = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];

  $upload['url']    = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];

  return $upload;

}
```

Comment: i dont understand how to use that code

Answer (score 0):

In code file, add below line

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('upload_captcha_background', $post->ID);
```

Form:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_captcha_background" id="upload_captcha_background" />
```

For more details about `media_handle_upload()`, Look at [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload).

Comment: how it will move my image in uploads folder which i created in my plugin